# Hide MSRP when special price is active

Tags: price

We display the manufacture suggested retail price on product and category page, but I want to edit our rule that when there is an special price, the msrp is hidden.

We use this code to display the msrp:

```
<?php $_price = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getMsrp()) ?>
    <?php if ($_product->getMsrp()): ?>
    <?php $_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true) ?>
    <p class="special-price">
    <span class="old-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId() ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>"><?php echo $_msrpPrice ?></span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What addition do I need to hide this, when there is an special price for that product?